Does Psalm 127:2 promote laidback attitude towards hard work?
We read in Psalm 127:2 ( NET);

It is vain for you to rise early, come home late, and work so hard for your food.
Yes, he provides for those whom he loves even when they sleep.

That Verse  apparently goes against the  spirit of the
maxim :" Early to bed and early to rise makes a man healthy, wealthy and wise". In tropical areas, a farmer reaches the field at sunup because he can't work once the sun becomes hot. After sundown, he would have to watch the field against the enemy who sows weed among the grain seeds ( Mtt 13:25)and later,  against birds and animals that feast on  the harvest. Many farmers camp in the field to protect the harvest, with hardly any sleep.  In so far as spiritual food is concerned, those who get up early to pray are said to be more focussed on prayer. Going by Jn 8;1-2, Jesus himself prayed through the night . My question therefore is: Does Psalm 127:2 promote laidback attitude towards hard work-- both for material and spiritual well-being ?

Jesus also said similar : Labour not for the meat which perisheth, but for that meat which endureth unto everlasting life, which the Son of man shall give unto you John 6:27. Up-voted +1.

The question is understandable given the astonishing translation used for Psalm 127:2, but this more literal translation clarifies the meaning. However, it must be preceded by verse 1 to make sense. Context is paramount here:

"Except the Lord build the house, they labour in vain that build it:
except the Lord keep the city, the watchman waketh but in vain. It is
vain for you to rise up early, to sit up late, to eat the bread of
sorrows: for so he giveth his beloved sleep." K.J.V.

The text is showing that unless the Lord God is in the work, or is keeping the city safe, the work and the watching is futile. But when the workman and the watchman are trusting in the strong arm of the Lord, their efforts will be blessed. Further, the Lord will grant sleep to those whom he loves.  And it is true that honest, hard work and vigilance go hand in glove with refreshing sleep. But that might be a separate question!
The answer is, quite to the contrary, the hard work and diligence of those who trust in the Lord and who love him will result in blessing. That applies equally to physical work, and spiritual work. Trusting in the Lord enables more diligence than would normally be the case.

Thanks, Anne for the definitive inputs. I chose NET because it presents the idea in an integrated manner. I don't think the ancient people were so stressed so as to crave for sleep. Why should it come as a gift from God , as KJV puts it ?

@KadalikattJosephSibichan  Your Q to me deserves posting on Hermeneutics, to see why there are variations in translations! This is not a hermeneutic point but I will just make comment that perhaps the translator of the NET was an incurable insomniac!

Thanks, Anne. I for one,prefer to let sleeping translators 'lie'  ( pun intended)  !

@KadalikattJosephSibichan  Smiles, but in this case it could be a translator unable to get to sleep!

Thanks, Anne. Some translate with black ink; some - with grey matter.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan  re "I don't think the ancient people were so stressed ..." --> I cannot imagine that they would possibly not be if they needed to depend on their or own (lack of) resources. || For the poorest of the poor, now or long ago, unless there is an "aid agency" or other often absent provider, life  is a continuous, immense and marginal struggle for survival. Sleep is an escape from the hardship of reality - and also an intrusion in the time available to seek to survive.  Yes?

The main point is that: our efforts are futile without God’s blessing.
Unless the Lord: (Psalm 127:1-2 NASB)



Unless the Lord builds a house, They who build it labor in vain;




Unless the Lord guards a city, The watchman stays awake in vain. It
is futile for you to rise up early, To stay up late, To eat the
bread of painful labor; This is how He gives to His beloved sleep.



It does not discourage hard work! It highlights the importance of relying on God.

Matthew 6:31-33 (NASB) says:

Do not worry then, saying, ‘What are we to eat?’ or ‘What are we to
drink?’ or ‘What are we to wear for clothing?’ For the Gentiles
eagerly seek all these things; for your heavenly Father knows that you
need all these things. But seek first His kingdom and His
righteousness, and all these things will be provided to you.

Jesus taught that we should not be anxious about our material needs but trust in God’s provision while seeking His kingdom and righteousness.
Human endeavors, whether building a house or guarding a city, are ultimately in vain without God’s involvement.

John 15:5 (NASB) says,

I am the vine, you are the branches; the one who remains in Me, and
I in him bears much fruit, for apart from Me you can do nothing.

1 Corinthians 3:6-7 (NASB) says,

I planted, Apollos watered, but God was causing the growth. So then
neither the one who plants nor the one who waters is anything, but God
who causes the growth.

It is God’s blessing and involvement that brings true success and fulfillment.

This is a collection of proverbs contained in a psalm. The second proverb is the saying mentioned in the OP. Here is the NABRE translation:

It is vain for you to rise early
and put off your rest at night, To eat bread earned by hard toil—
all this God gives to his beloved in sleep.

The psalmist's point here is much like that of Jesus In Matthew 6:

Do not worry about your life, what you will eat, or about your body,
what you will wear. Is not life more than food and the body more than
clothing? 26 Look at the birds in the sky; they do not sow or reap,
they gather nothing into barns, yet your heavenly Father feeds them.

The OP asks if this promotes' a laid-back attitude toward hard work. The answer is no - if we read it in context - for it is preceded by another proverb, from which it should not be isolated:

Unless the Lord build the house,
they labor in vain who build.

The implication here is that "they" do NOT labor in vain if God is in charge of the project. Hard work is not discouraged, but one's labor must be put in the service of the LORD. Moreover, when one approaches life with the right priorities, he can be assured of God's protection and sustenance.

Are we sure that the context wasn't altered by adding that 'unless' bit just to adjust its meaning into a different direction - hardworking peasant.
